# Typo in rails migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Folks,

I have a situation where I created a rails migration file which updates the value of an attribute in a model. I ran this migration on several production deployments and then realized the table was never updated due to a typo. What is the best practice to fix this, should I be updating my current migration file with the fix and commit it and then re-run the migration OR should I create a new migration file and remove this migration.

Comment: If the migration never ran, so you can go ahead and edit it directly.

Comment: How do I figure out if the migration ran, how does rails decide that, for example in this case it did try to run the migration for sure but did not do anything since there was a typo

Comment: Can you provide the migration snippet? Depending on the typo, did it raise an exception or did it create the attribute with a wrong name?

Comment: Well, if it didn't do anything you can safely assume that it didn't run. So just edit it and re-run.

Answer (score 2):

If you ran a migration and it succeeded and then you update your current migration file and try to re-run the migrations, Rails won't update your schema because the migration version will be the same as the current db version.

If you do a `rake db:migrate:status` you should be able to see the list of migrations and the ones that have been applied or not.

Based on that, if your migration says `status: down` it means that it still hasn't been applied to the database.

If it has already been applied to the db you can have a number of options.

1. `rake db:rollback` update your file then re-run that migration
2. Create a new file that fixes the typo. Note that even removing the migration with the wrong  data won't fix your database depending on what you did to the table and how you fixed it on the new migration.